# Accessing property of observable object inside observable array - knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Been learning knockout and having fun, but I'm stuck on something that I assume is so simple: accessing the properties of an observable object inside an observable array. **I need to get the "multiplierValue" from the activeCompMultiplier object inside the activeCompMultipliers array.**

Here's all my relevant code:

First off, the object that is created and pushed into the array. This is what I'm trying to talk to:

```
var activeCompMultiplier = function (multiplierValue) {
    this.multiplierValue = ko.observable(multiplierValue);
}
```

And this is the observable array that contains the observable objects:

```
self.activeCompMultipliers = ko.observableArray();
```

Here's the line that creates a new object and pushes it into the array:

```
self.activeCompMultipliers.push(new activeCompMultiplier(1));
```

And finally, when the input field triggers a 'change' event, this is what is called. I'm using an alert() to debug the issue:

```
self.inputChanged = function (rowIndex) {

    alert("Multiplier is: " + self.activeCompMultipliers()[rowIndex].multiplierValue() + "\n At index: " + rowIndex);
}
```

Annnnd here my related HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: activeParts">
                <tr>
                    <td class="ShoppingEntry" data-bind="text: $data"></td>
                    <td class="Textbox" >
                        <input type="number" class="TextBoxInput"
                          data-bind="value: $root.activeCompMultipliers()[$index()], 
                                     event: { change: inputChanged.bind(self, $index())},
                                     attr: {id: 'Textbox' + $index()}" /></td>     
                    <td class="DeleteCell">
                        <input type="image" src="/Assets/list_remove.png" class="DeleteButtonInput" data-bind="click: deactivatePart"/></td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
```

I assume its a syntactical issue as JS isn't my strongest language, but I've triple-checked using parenthesis to un-wrap KO observables, so maybe it's a scope issue?

All of my JS is within a `function ViewModel() {...}` function, that is then bound via `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());`

As a long-time lurker, I appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

3 points:

1. You're not looping over `activeCompMultipliers` but using the `$index()` of `activeParts` to access it, does this mean these 2 arrays have the same size and are linked?
2. If the `index()` is correct, the value is bound to an `activeCompMultiplier` instance, it should be bound to its `multiplierValue` field:

   ```
   <input type="number" class="TextBoxInput"
       data-bind="value: $root.activeCompMultipliers()[$index()].multiplierValue,
   ```
3. The change event is bound to `inputChanged` which you changed its scope to `self`, but what is `self` at that point? and its useless as that function already references the right `self`. Should be:

   ```
   event: { change: function() { inputChanged($index()); } }
   ```

   or at least:

   ```
   event: { change: inputChanged.bind(null, $index()) }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @manji. To your points:
1) Yes these arrays are the same size and linked

2) That's right, not sure why I missed that...but adding .multiplierValue causes my HTML to be screwy

3) Is the semi-colon before the ending-brace necessary? It seems to cause problems.

Comment: I think I'm going to try a different route without using an observable since it might be overkill anyways. I'll just grab the value passed in when inputChanged is called for the calculations.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo, the example with `bind` does not need a semi-colon.